# Adb shell verify password

Tags: shell, passwords, adb

I am looking for installing apk apps
For my car head unit but adb shell requst verify password .. **adb shell**
Please input verify password

Comment: ADB as designed by Google does not require a password. So if your head-unit requires one, then the password check has been implemented by the manufacturer of the head-unit/car. You have not included any information about the head-unit and your car, so we can't help you on this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.